# The context for node is NULL, but the context node in rules_node_is_of_type requires a value

Tags: views, 8, nodes, rules

I am working on Drupal 8 project

I have made a content type by name glossary having machine name **glossary**
Also, I have made one field in it, i.e. description having machine name **field_description**.
As it is a content type, in order to add a Glossary term via REST,
I am using the following

URL: http://example.com/entity/node?_format=json

METHOD: POST

Passing Headers as Authorization with its value & Content-Type as application/json

and Body as

```
{
  "type":[{"target_id":"glossary"}],
  "title":[{"value":"haha"}],
  "field_description":[{"value":"Howasdasdd are you?"}]
}
```

> Status **500 Internal Server Error**
>
> Response A fatal error occurred: Internal Server Error

I checked into Drupal logs I got the following message.

> Drupal\rules\Exception\EvaluationException: The context for node is
>   NULL, but the context node in rules_node_is_of_type requires a value.
>   in
>   Drupal\rules\Plugin\RulesExpression\RulesCondition->prepareContext()
>   (line 98 of
>   /var/www/vhosts/readyresponders.org/staging/dashboard/modules/contrib/rules/src/Context/ContextHandlerTrait.php).

Comment: Have the same issue... I'm pretty sure it's a problem with the rules module. It seems pretty flakey in D8. Not sure that it's in the code for rules/src/Context/ContextHandlerTrait.php or in rules/src/Plugin/Condition/NodeIsOfType.php. I've been looking at it for a while without any progress.